# Настройка времени при отправке письма

Tags: php, дата

Класс для отправки письма взял [здесь](http://soft.unibix.ru/unibix-php/php-smtp-mail-class):
Там есть строчка `$headers  = "Date: ".date("D, d M Y H:i:s",(time()-(5*60*60))) . " UT\r\n";`
Однако как бы я не менял дату, письма приходят в будущем времени на 2 часа.

Скажите, где и что еще можно прописать чтоб избавиться от этой фичи.

Comment: Сделайте `$headers  = 'Date: '. gmdate('r') . "\r\n";`

Comment: скорее всего проблема в настройках хоста. проверьте время